# Who has priority on a dual carriageway when turning right?

Tags: uk, driving

In the satellite photo that I have attached above who has priority to go, assuming both sides of the dual carriageway are free, as I want to go onto the central reservation so that I can then turn right onto the carriageway. However, the car that is already on the carriageway wants to turn into the town road.

Satellite photo of the location in question:

[image]

[Link to location on Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/@51.0900541,-1.295161,190m/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en-GB)

Comment: At the give way points (double broken lines across the carriageways with the triangle sign in the road), neither of the turning vehicles have priority over each other - once either is past the give way point, they have priority over the other traffic. Neither turning vehicle has priority over traffic on the A33.

Comment: Your drawing is incomplete and lacks all the details (yield signs) required to answer your question. Please try to improive it instead of relying on a link to Google Street View.

Comment: In the US, you would be required to yield to oncoming traffic.  They are already on the road and you are entering.  It doesn't matter if either of you are turning or proceeding forward.  This presumes the other vehicle doen't have a sign indicating otherwise (99.99% no).

Comment: I thought it would be the same as this case http://slightlyodd.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/right_hand_rule_current_sto.jpg (ignore the arrows) so red - blue - green. But the fact that the yield in the carriageway stops before the path of the car turning across makes it ambiguous.

Comment: @stanri In the link you posted, blue has priority over red - a car turning right (across traffic) into the side road has priority over one turning left (not crossing traffic). I thought that was specified in the highway code, but I can't find it in the latest version online..

Comment: @NickC I didn't know that was the case in the UK. The article that image is from (http://slightlyodd.com/2010/03/new-zealands-stupid-right-hand-turn-rule) is all about how the NZ law changed. I'm only familiar with the driving laws in South Africa/Australia. I'm curious about that rule in practise. How does the car turning right(blue) distinguish between  a red car going straight and a red car turning? Surely it only will know when the red car has gone past (or not). It seems silly for the red car to stop so that the blue car can go; the red car going first would be quicker in any case.

Comment: @stanri The red car ought to be signalling if it's turning! I think the idea is that in busy situations, the blue car will be holding up a lot of traffic while it waits for an oncoming gap. If the red car lets it go first, that removes the hold-up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that traffic going W->S has priority over traffic going N->W.

The logic behind it goes: As you approach from the west, you have a give way line. You therefore have to give way to traffic on the main road (S->N). As the other car approaches from the north, he too has a give way line - but his line faces onto the turning right lane, not onto the main carriageway - therefore he has to give way to traffic in that lane, i.e. you.

Either way I'd always treat it with extreme caution, watching both the main road traffic and the crossing traffic. I've seen some very close calls there, including having to take avoiding action myself about 10 years ago when a car going W->S pulled straight out in front of me as I was heading down the main road N->S...

Comment: This doesn't sound right to me. I don't understand the logical leap you're making there. Can you give some Highway Code sources that would support this?

Comment: The highway code doesn't mention this kind of situation, as far as I can tell - nor does it mention what to do when two cars approach the non-priority sides of a crossroads together. My logic is that, for the car going N->W, the give way line is at the point it crosses the path of the car going W->S

Comment: I've just spoken to a colleague who lives in Winchester, and she thinks the opposite to me, with the comment of "nobody knows, and anyone turning W->S is suicidal, with the speed people come down there, I always go a different route to avoid it"

Comment: Page 51 of the UK traffic signs manual has a diagram of essentially this situation, but it's still a bit unclear to me what the right-of-way should be: https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/223667/traffic-signs-manual-chapter-05.pdf